# htaccess rules to rewrite subfolder to a GET variable

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm not very experienced with htaccess. today I fail in writing an .htaccess to rewrite a url.

What I want:
My project is hosted on a subdomain e.g. sub.domain.com

My htaccess should manage:

1. `sub.domain.com` should redirect to `www.domain.com` (Redirect 301, that's clear)
2. subfolders should be put as GET variable e.g. `sub.domain.com/test` to `www.domain.com?var=test`
3. the subfolder `/admin` shouldn't be redirected

Thanks in advance for tips!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it for you:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =sub.example.com
# Following condition added to support changed requirement, see comments
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(?:^|&)var=
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/?var=$1 [R=301,L]
```

This will drop any query string that was in the original request. If you want to keep any query string, and just append 'var=...' to it, then add `QSA` to the flags at the end of the last line, separated by a comma.

Comment: Thanks @SuperDuperApps
In the end the redirect works, but there's one thing: It seems that the request redirect multiple times and the url looks like sub.example.com/?var=&var=&var=&var=&var=&var=&var=&var=&var=&var=something

Comment: You're welcome Stefan. Please consider acceptng my answer with the tick at the top left of it, so the question shows as answered and I get a bit of rep for it :) Welcome to Stack Overflow :)

Comment: There's one thing as mentioned above.
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =sub.domain.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin/
RewriteRule ^$\/(.*)$ ?e=$1 [QSA,R=301,L]

leads to something like:
/?e=&e=&e=&e=&e=&e=&e=&e=&e=&e=&e=&e=&e=&e=&e=&e=&e=&e=&e=&e=&e=val

Seems that the page redirects multiple times... (Sorry for bothering you with it :))

Comment: Well you changed the rule, you said it should redirect from sub to www, then removed that. I added a condition to check for var in the query string which will prevent the loop.

Comment: You also changed the rule match, I don't see how that can even be matching anything at all.

Comment: Thius is my htaccess:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =sub.domain.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sub.domain.com/?e=$1 [QSA,R=301,L] (I don't want to switch the domain)

Comment: Sorry, just seen your changes. In the end this is what I currently implemented:
RewriteEngine on  #
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =sub.domain.com #
# Following condition added to support changed requirement, see comments
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(?:^|&)e= #
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin/ #
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/assets/ #added, because there I have css etc.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sub.domain.com?e=$1 #[R=301,L,QSA]

I want to redirect from a subfolder in my sub-domain to the index in the same sub-domain, added by thee subfolder name as GETvariable.

Comment: I am really thankful for your effort... And promise to go deeper into htaccess syntax...